# Any reason to prefer credit cards that do not use an issuing bank?

Tags: credit-card, banking, consumer-protection

Considering that credit card companies are required to state if a card is issued by a third-party or issuing bank, is there any incentive to avoid these types of cards and prefer those issued by the primary company itself?

Are there security and/or consumer-protection concerns worth noting?

Does this make dealing with fraudulent activity more difficult?

Why would a consumer care whether or not a card is provided by an issuing bank?

Comment: United states? And do you have any examples? I literally cannot think of one except Amex... Most (all) branded credit cards have an issuing bank, HSBC has a big business of branded credit cards, the bank just takes a secondary position to the branding.  The amazon cards the southwest card are both Chase, etc.

Comment: Discover I believe also falls into this category, if I understand correctly...

Comment: I think the difference is marginal either way, but if anything, maybe there's a slight advantage towards those *with* a separate third-party bank, because you possibly get two different customer service departments you can speak to if there's a problem, both of which would have incentive to help you.

Comment: Researching cards, I noticed Ally Bank (USA) offers a credit card issued by TD Bank. PayPal issues cards under Synchrony Bank.

Comment: Some store credit cards are funded by the store and run by the store. I don't have statistics on how many are run by the store and how many by a bank. I only have a couple of store credit cards, and when I look at my bill they all take me to a web site with the name of a bank on it.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, there are no difference between a credit card issued by a bank (Chase, BoA, etc.) or not (Amex). Discover does have a "traditional" banking side to it (i.e. checking/savings accounts). All these companies are considered "banks" since they all make loans. A major plus to having a credit card issued by a bank is that you can then have access to the other services that bank offers.